# iOS: WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView... <NSInvalidArgumentException> data parameter is nil

Tags: ios, exception, webview, alert

My app is coming together now. It's purpose is to search the internet and return JSON data. I realised the importance in catching exceptions such as when there's no internet connection. Now my app will show an alertview explaining that there's no internet connection available - this happens when the NSData returned is nil (because of the lack of internet) so how would I go about catching the exception itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not looking for an exception, you're just looking for the reachability of the network. This post has great info:

[How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)